# responsive jquery code - how to rigger only part on window resize + document ready?

Tags: jquery

I build a jQuery slider (plus some other things on a certain site).
The jQuery slider is responsive, but the responsiveness is only on document ready, and not on page load.
If I try loading it `onpageload` + `document ready`, all click functions are repeated forever:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){

  var sliderwidth = $(".theslider .wpb_wrapper .idoslider").width();

  if (sliderwidth > 869) {
    var itemwidth = parseInt(sliderwidth, 10)/ 3;
    $(".theslider .wpb_wrapper .idoslider .idoslideritem").css("width", itemwidth);
    var sliderinwidth = parseInt(sliderwidth, 10)* 3;
    var firstpos = parseInt(itemwidth, 10)* 6;
    var endpos = parseInt(firstpos, 10)- 1;
  }
  else if (sliderwidth < 870 && sliderwidth > 579) {
    var itemwidth = parseInt(sliderwidth, 10)/ 2;
    $(".theslider .wpb_wrapper .idoslider .idoslideritem").css("width", itemwidth);
    var sliderinwidth = parseInt(sliderwidth, 10)* 4.5;
    var firstpos = parseInt(itemwidth, 10)* 7;
    var endpos = parseInt(firstpos - itemwidth - 1);
  }
  else {
    $(".theslider .wpb_wrapper .idoslider .idoslideritem").css("width", sliderwidth);
    var itemwidth = sliderwidth;
    var sliderinwidth = parseInt(sliderwidth, 10)* 9;
    var firstpos = parseInt(itemwidth, 10)* 8;
    var endpos = parseInt(firstpos, 10)- 1;
  }

  var leftedge = parseInt(-1);

  $(".theslider .wpb_wrapper .idoslider .sliderin").css({"width": sliderinwidth, "left": -firstpos});

    var sliderheight = $(".theslider .wpb_wrapper .idoslider .idoslideritem").height();
    $(".theslider .wpb_wrapper .idoslider").css("height", sliderheight);

  $(".theslider .wpb_wrapper .idopagination .nexter").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().find(".js-wpv-view-layout .sliderin").animate({ "left": "+=" + itemwidth }, "slow", function() {
  var posn = $(this).position();
    if (posn.left > leftedge) {
      $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".nexter").css("pointer-events", "none")
      $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".nexter img").css("filter", "grayscale(100%)")
    }
    else {
      $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".nexter").css("pointer-events", "initial")
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".nexter img").css("filter", "none")
    }
  if(posn.left < -endpos) {
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".prever").css("pointer-events", "none")
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".prever img").css("filter", "grayscale(100%)")
    }
    else {
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".prever").css("pointer-events", "initial")
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".prever img").css("filter", "none")
    }
  });
  });

  $(".theslider .wpb_wrapper .idopagination .prever").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().find(".js-wpv-view-layout .sliderin").animate({ "left": "-=" + itemwidth }, "slow", function() {
    var posp = $(this).position();
    if(posp.left > leftedge) {
      $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".nexter").css("pointer-events", "none")
      $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".nexter img").css("filter", "grayscale(100%)")
    }
  else {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".nexter").css("pointer-events", "initial")
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".nexter img").css("filter", "none")
  }
    if(posp.left < -endpos) {
      $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".prever").css("pointer-events", "none")
      $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".prever img").css("filter", "grayscale(100%)")
    }
  else {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".prever").css("pointer-events", "initial")
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".prever img").css("filter", "none")
  }
  });
  });
});
```

If I try only to load the responsive part in the code, the responsiveness isn't loaded on first page load.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

The idea was to create a function for all element to appear on window resize, then place them both outside the function (to load on document load) and in it:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){

    // SLIDER //

    var sliderwidth = $(".theslider .wpb_wrapper .idoslider").width();

  if (sliderwidth > 869) {
    var itemwidth = parseInt(sliderwidth, 10)/ 3;
    $(".theslider .wpb_wrapper .idoslider .idoslideritem").css("width", itemwidth);
    var sliderinwidth = parseInt(sliderwidth, 10)* 3;
    var firstpos = parseInt(itemwidth, 10)* 6;
    var endpos = parseInt(firstpos, 10)- 1;
  }
  else if (sliderwidth < 870 && sliderwidth > 579) {
    var itemwidth = parseInt(sliderwidth, 10)/ 2;
    $(".theslider .wpb_wrapper .idoslider .idoslideritem").css("width", itemwidth);
    var sliderinwidth = parseInt(sliderwidth, 10)* 4.5;
    var firstpos = parseInt(itemwidth, 10)* 7;
    var endpos = parseInt(firstpos - itemwidth - 1);
  }
  else {
    $(".theslider .wpb_wrapper .idoslider .idoslideritem").css("width", sliderwidth);
    var itemwidth = sliderwidth;
    var sliderinwidth = parseInt(sliderwidth, 10)* 9;
    var firstpos = parseInt(itemwidth, 10)* 8;
    var endpos = parseInt(firstpos, 10)- 1;
  }

  var leftedge = parseInt(-1);

  $(".theslider .wpb_wrapper .idoslider .sliderin").css({"width": sliderinwidth, "left": -firstpos});

    var sliderheight = $(".theslider .wpb_wrapper .idoslider .idoslideritem").height();
    $(".theslider .wpb_wrapper .idoslider").css("height", sliderheight);

  function modifyWidth() {

  var sliderwidth = $(".theslider .wpb_wrapper .idoslider").width();

  if (sliderwidth > 869) {
    var itemwidth = parseInt(sliderwidth, 10)/ 3;
    $(".theslider .wpb_wrapper .idoslider .idoslideritem").css("width", itemwidth);
    var sliderinwidth = parseInt(sliderwidth, 10)* 3;
    var firstpos = parseInt(itemwidth, 10)* 6;
    var endpos = parseInt(firstpos, 10)- 1;
  }
  else if (sliderwidth < 870 && sliderwidth > 579) {
    var itemwidth = parseInt(sliderwidth, 10)/ 2;
    $(".theslider .wpb_wrapper .idoslider .idoslideritem").css("width", itemwidth);
    var sliderinwidth = parseInt(sliderwidth, 10)* 4.5;
    var firstpos = parseInt(itemwidth, 10)* 7;
    var endpos = parseInt(firstpos - itemwidth - 1);
  }
  else {
    $(".theslider .wpb_wrapper .idoslider .idoslideritem").css("width", sliderwidth);
    var itemwidth = sliderwidth;
    var sliderinwidth = parseInt(sliderwidth, 10)* 9;
    var firstpos = parseInt(itemwidth, 10)* 8;
    var endpos = parseInt(firstpos, 10)- 1;
  }

  var leftedge = parseInt(-1);

  $(".theslider .wpb_wrapper .idoslider .sliderin").css({"width": sliderinwidth, "left": -firstpos});

    var sliderheight = $(".theslider .wpb_wrapper .idoslider .idoslideritem").height();
    $(".theslider .wpb_wrapper .idoslider").css("height", sliderheight);

    }

  $(".theslider .wpb_wrapper .idopagination .nexter").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().find(".js-wpv-view-layout .sliderin").animate({ "left": "+=" + itemwidth }, "slow", function() {
  var posn = $(this).position();
    if (posn.left > leftedge) {
      $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".nexter").css("pointer-events", "none")
      $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".nexter img").css("filter", "grayscale(100%)")
    }
    else {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".nexter").css("pointer-events", "initial")
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".nexter img").css("filter", "none")
    }
  if(posn.left < -endpos) {
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".prever").css("pointer-events", "none")
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".prever img").css("filter", "grayscale(100%)")
    }
    else {
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".prever").css("pointer-events", "initial")
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".prever img").css("filter", "none")
    }
  });
  });

  $(".theslider .wpb_wrapper .idopagination .prever").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().find(".js-wpv-view-layout .sliderin").animate({ "left": "-=" + itemwidth }, "slow", function() {
    var posp = $(this).position();
    if(posp.left > leftedge) {
      $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".nexter").css("pointer-events", "none")
      $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".nexter img").css("filter", "grayscale(100%)")
    }
  else {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".nexter").css("pointer-events", "initial")
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".nexter img").css("filter", "none")
  }
    if(posp.left < -endpos) {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".prever").css("pointer-events", "none")
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".prever img").css("filter", "grayscale(100%)")
    }
  else {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".prever").css("pointer-events", "initial")
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".prever img").css("filter", "none")
  }
  });
  });

// END //

   $(window).resize(function () {
        modifyWidth();
    });
});
```